# How to cast Class type(Reference Type) to Struct type(Value Type) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, class, struct, nsstring

In Swift `String` is implemented as `struct` while in Objective C `NSString` implemented as `Class`. As `struct` is Value Type and Class is reference type. Then how compiler converts `struct` to `Class` using casting.

As we are writing below code then it will work fine:

```
let swiftString : String = "Swift String"
print("Cast as NSString : \(swiftString as? NSString)")
```

This successfully cast `string` to `NSString`.

While rule of [Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338) suggest that you can cast object only from same class hierarchy.

> Type casting is a way to check the type of an instance, or to treat
>   that instance as a different superclass or subclass from somewhere
>   else in its own class hierarchy.

When I tried to cast my `struct` object with `Class` object then it fails.

So what mechanism Apple using for Swift to cast `struct` to `Class` ?

Comment: I would love to read detailed blogs/posts on "So what mechanism Apple using for Swift to cast struct to Class" or "how bridging works"

Comment: As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string) states, _"The String type bridges with the Objective-C class NSString"_, so probably that's why it works. As of how this is implemented under the hood, you have to ask Apple about it, since `Objective-C` is not open source.

Comment: Consider there is a difference between *Type Casting* and *Bridge Casting* (the latter is used by `String`-`NSString` and is not covered in the linked Language Guide chapter).